# how do I obtain or create a .srprofile file when nuget doesn't create it?

Tags: .net, specflow, specrun

To configure and use many features of SpecRun (beefed up version of Specflow, the cucumber for .NET), you need some sort of `.sfprofile` file.  A file "`default.sfprofile`" is supposedly and (I assume) typically created for you when the Nuget package is installed.  But it did not do so for me.

Is there another way to trigger the creation of "`default.sfprofile`"?  If not, will all be well if I create it myself?  If that will work, could someone please post what the initial contents of this file should be?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SpecFlow+ Runner configuration file template is available as Item Template if you have the SpecFlow for Visual Studio extension installed:

[image]

It is the last one in the list.

Be aware that VS will try to create it as Default1.srProfile by default. You need to adjust the filename manually.

Old and outdated answer:

The template for the file is in packages\SpecRun.SpecFlow.1.2.0\content\Default.srprofile.pp

Copy that and replace the {...} Placeholders with your values. projectId is a Guid.

Comment: where is the packages folder?

Comment: In old projects it is in the solution folder.

Comment: For newer projects it is under %userprofile%\.nuget

Answer (score 0):

[Andreas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34627656/97890) is correct.  But I've since discovered *why* nuget failed to install SpecRun.SpecFlow correctly.  I believe it had to do with artifacts left over from a previous installation, which was later removed.  It installed correctly after I:

1. Removed the "SpecRun.Runner.1.2.0" and "SpecRun.SpecFlow.1.2.0" directories from my solution's \packages\ directory
2. Removed the "SpecRun.Runner.1.2.0" directory from C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\Temp\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions\
3. Removed the "obj\debug" and "bin\debug" directories from the project in question.
4. (this was definitely part of the problem:)  Removed these files from my project:  "Default.srprofile", "runtests.cmd", "SpecRunTestProfile.xsd".  These were removed from my solution with the previous uninstall, but were still there in the file system.
5. For good measure, checked the entire project from source control and ran via the Nuget command line (`Install-Package SpecRun.SpecFlow`), because I was desperate and trying everything at this point.

After doing all that, SpecRun.Runner installed correctly.  Not sure *all* of that was needed, but at least several  of them were, each of them individually didn't do the trick.  Oh, and another gotcha:

6. Even when mostly successful (got my shiny new "Default.srprofile"!), I still had to fix something in the app.config:  the install correctly added `<unitTestProvider name="SpecRun" />` element, but mistakenly left in the old `<unitTestProvider name="MsTest" />` element.  Had to take that out for all to be joyful.

Of course, now I have [this issue](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/534), but that's unrelated.